ACT practice test, aren't both $3$ and $12$ viable answers?
The question

For which of the following values of $c$ will there be two distinct real solutions to the equation $5x^2+16x+c=0$?
and the possible answers are:$\quad$
$\text{F}.\space3\\
\text{G}.\space12 \\
\text{H}.\space14 \\
\text{J}.\space 15 \\
\text{K}. \space20$


I calculated the answer $(5x+6)(x+2)=0$ using $c=12$, and I still can't figure out why it would be wrong.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

For there to be two distinct real solutions to $5x^2+16x+c=0$, the discriminant $256-20c$ must be positive.

But isn't 256 - 20c, with c being 12 positive? That should equal 16.

@GeoffreyTrang And that's true for both $c=3$ and $c=12$.  The post is correct.  It's a bad question.  I think the downvotes are ridiculous.

@RobertShore Thank you, I thought the question was bad but I wanted to confirm with people who know math better than me.

It's possible that option F is supposed to be $13$ (the tens digit got dropped by accident somewhere along the line), which would make only $12$ be the answer. This would also explain why the answer choices are not decimal-aligned, which I would have expected to be the case. Of course, this doesn't explain why $3$ is  the answer (should be $12$ if the $3$ was supposed to be $13)$ nor why $3$ appears at the top rather than $12$ (since having $13$ at the top keeps the answer choices from being in numerical order), unless maybe some additional editing was done after $13$ became $3.$

I do not believe this question should have been closed.  It shows real work toward a solution and also shows the reason it's of interest to the poster (it's part of an ACT practice test).  I'm voting to reopen.

I completely agree with the comment of @RobertShore.  I consider a a math problem where the official solution is wrong to be an exceptional case, which by itself has relevance.  Further, as Robert Shore indicated, the original poster showed work.  What else was the original poster supposed to do, but either ask a teacher, or post the question on a forum, like MathSE?

In order for there to be two distinct real-valued solutions to $ax^2 + bx + c = 5x^2 + 16x + c = 0$, the discriminant $b^2 - 4ac$ must be strictly positive; hence we require
$$16^2 - 4(5)(c) > 0,$$
or
$$c < \frac{64}{5} = 12.8.$$
Consequently, both choices (F) and (G) are valid.  In the case of (F), the roots are
$$x \in \{-3, -\tfrac{1}{5}\},$$
and in the case of (G), the roots are
$$x \in \{-2, -\tfrac{6}{5}\}.$$
As there is no obvious qualitative difference between these two solution sets with respect to the stated question criteria, I would consider the correct answer to be choices (F) and (G).

Completing the square works as well:
$5x^2 + 16x + c = 5 \left( x^2 + {16 \over 5} x \right)  + c  = 5 \left( (x + 8/5)^2 - (8/5)^2 \right) + c$
The expression is clearly positive for large $|x|$, so it will have two distinct negative roots if and only if it has a negative minimum.   The minimum is $5(-(8/5)^2) + c$, which is negative if $c < 5 (8/5)^2 = 64/5 = 12.8$.  (F) and (G) are both right.
